# What are the limitations of a password used to protected an Access 2010 database?

Tags: ms-access-2010

According to this page:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx

The maximum number of characters in a password is 14.

But this page encourages you to use 14 *or more* characters in a password:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx?CTT=3

My own testing has shown that I can use up to 20 characters.

Has anyone found better (or more consistent documentation) on Access 2010 passwords?  Or perhaps done some extensive testing to determine what the real limits are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different resource which confirms your 20 Character limit in MS Access 2010.

http://www.databasezone.com/techdocs/acclimit.html

It lists that up to MS Access 2003, the maximum password length was in fact 14 characters long.  In MS Access 2007, the introduction of the .accdb format did away with user account passwords and opted for a more robust cryptography API, which supports up to 20 characters.

I am unsure why the Microsoft website specifies a 14 character maximum. I can only speculate that this is to cover those who are using MS Access 2007+ to use an older .mdb format database which would not support a full 20 characters for the password.

Also, while not necessarily a limitation of the password itself, when using a password on a .accdb format database, the encryption forces page level locking on the database - which can limit the users ability to issue transactions against the underlying data in a shared environment (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx  -- Search for "page-level").

Comment: Thanks.  That link confirms my theory that it's 20.  Good point about the page level locking.  I'm not worried about page-level locking as my app is rarely used as multi-user.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this page is very old and the Access specifications page hasn't been updated since with regard to password length.

However, following a question in another Access forum recently I did some testing. Access APPEARS to let you enter more than 20 characters as a password.
In fact I successfully tested with 26, 256 & even 512 password characters. However this was an illusion and only the first 20 characters entered are saved.
The limit remains as 20 characters with one proviso. If you use a 20 character password with a linked BE table, the link works but you will get a 'Not a Valid Password' error on opening the table. The effective limit for tables in linked databases = 19